# constexpr if and the return value optimization

Tags: c++, c++17, rvo

I have this code:

```
#include <string>

class A {
 public:
//    A(A const &) = delete;   // Code fails if this is uncommented.
    explicit A(int);
    explicit A(::std::string const &);

 private:
    ::std::string myname_;
    int foo_;
};

static constexpr bool which = false;

A test(::std::string const &s, int a)
{
    if constexpr (which) {
        A x{a};
        return x;
    } else {
        A y{s};
        return y;
    }
}
```

This code fails if `A` has a deleted copy constructor. But, given the rules about return type for functions with `if constexpr` in them, it seems like the compiler should be applying RVO here.

Is there a reason why it isn't, other than it being an overlooked case in the language specification?

Comment: On what compiler does this "fail"?

Comment: @aschepler - It fails if you uncomment out the deletion of the move constructor. And it does on both gcc and clang.

Comment: `if constexpr` only discards code in a template instantiation.  In non-template code both branches are retained.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585634/is-if-constexpr-useful-outside-of-templates) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300760/wrong-understanding-of-if-constexpr).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - That's very interesting to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `if constexpr`

Simply this code is not allowed to compile:

```
class A {
 public:
    A(A const &) = delete;
    explicit A(int);
};

A test(int a)
{
    A x{a};
    return x; // <-- error call to a deleted constructor `A(A const &) = delete;`
}
```

The changes in C++17 you are thinking of have to do with [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) and don't apply to NRVO because `x` is not a prvalue.

For instance this code was illegal pre C++17 and now it is allowed:

```
A test(int a)
{
    return A{a}; // legal since C++17
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that does indeed answer my question. Interesting. I was confused about how the mandatory optimization worked.

Comment: I don't understand why `A x{a};` is illegal

Comment: The other thing going on: It would be legal if `A` had a non-deleted and public move constructor, even though the expression is an lvalue. But declaring a deleted copy constructor means there is no move constructor at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is non-mandatory copy elision:

(emphasis mine)

> - In a [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return), when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a
>     function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the
>     same class type (ignoring [cv-qualification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)) as the function return
>     type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return
>     value optimization".
>
> This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy/`move
>   (since C++11)` constructor is not called, **it still must be present and
>   accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the
>   program is ill-formed**:

---

BTW: Note that in your code, both the `if` part and `else` part of the [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) statement will be checked.

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if
>   constexpr is not a substitute for the [#if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional) preprocessing directive:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     if constexpr(false) {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but the other answer is a more direct answer to my question. Had I seen this one first, I would've started an argument about that not being true in C++17. :-) I would've been wrong, but the path leading to me realizing that would've been a lot longer.